# How can I setup a GitBlit repository preventing users to push?

Tags: git, gitblit

I would like that authenticated users can only:

- view
- clone
- fetch/pull from it?

basically I want prevent users, even authenticated ones, to push to this git repo. But for other git repos on the same GitBlit I may desire to have authenticated users to *also* push to those repos.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Gitblit 1.2.0, released 2012-12-31, introduced [finer-grained permissions](http://gitblit.com/administration.html#H6) which address your exact needs.

The enhanced permissions, however, are still not as flexible as Gitolite which allows per-ref permissions.  Gitblit's permissions apply to the repository, not to a particular ref.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [Gitblit FAQ](http://gitblit.com/faq.html), the easiest way would be to install in addition of Gitblit a **[gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)**, which is an [authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html).

That will allow you to put in place all kind of access restriction, based on user authentication.

Comment: No, this is not an option in my scenario: I choose GitBlit because it strictly follow the KISS principle. While I'm able to install gitolite this is not the route I intend to go: I need a *simple* method of prohibiting uses to push content. Anyway thank you.

Comment: @Fabio the thing is: authorization management + git + KISS = gitolite. ;-)